# ECONNREFUSED with NodeJS and InfluxDb on docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, nestjs, influxdb

I've got a problem with connect to my InfluxDB instance running in docker.

I pull InfluxDB image with this command:

```
docker pull influxdb:2.4.0
```

and run locally with using Docker Desktop, everything is ok and below is my logs:

[image]

but now I want to connect to this instance like below:

```
export const influx = new Influx.InfluxDB({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8086,
  database: 'ocean_tides',
  schema: [
    {
      measurement: 'tide',
      fields: { height: Influx.FieldType.FLOAT },
      tags: ['unit', 'location']
    }
  ]
});
```

and when I try to test connection like this:

```
await influx.getDatabaseNames()
```

server threw me this:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8086
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 127.0.0.1 or localhost to connect to the service outside the container!

Please replace `127.0.0.1` / `localhost` to `host.docker.internal` in order to connect to the host machine.